# working with JS polymorphism & method overriding

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I'm currently studying the basics of javascript and I'm having a hard time understanding this diagram(below). When FirmAnswer.get() is called, why is the value 42!!? Isn't it should be undefined!! because if I'm not mistaken the **this** in **return this.val** in *function fn2()* refers to firmAnswer.

***credits to the owner of the diagram***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because if I'm not mistaken the this in return this.val in function fn2() refers to firmAnswer

Yes, it does, but when you try to retrieve a property (`val`) from an object, if the object itself doesn't have that property, the JavaScript engine looks to the object's prototype. `firmAnswer`'s prototype is `answer` (because that's what `Object.create` was used to set up), which *does* have a `val`, and so that property's value is used. This is called the *prototype chain* and is key to prototypical inheritance.

Here's a somewhat simpler example:

```js
// Create an object with a `val`
var p = {
  val: "p's value"
};

// Create an object using `p` as its prototype
var o = Object.create(p);

// Use `val` from `o` -- since `o` doesn't have `val`, the engine
// looks to `p`
snippet.log(o.val); // "p's value"

// Give `o` its own `val`
o.val = "o's value";

// Use it
snippet.log(o.val); // "o's value"

// Since this is based on whether `o` has `val` at all
// (not the *value* of `val`), we can *remove* `val`
// from `o` and start using `p`'s again:

// Remove `val` from `o` entirely
delete o.val;

// Use `val` again -- and we're back to using `p`'s
snippet.log(o.val); // "p' s value ""
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a troublesome topic, I'll give you that.

You are correct that `this` refers to `firmAnswer`, but even though `firmAnswer` does not have a `val` property explicitly assigned to it, `val` is not `undefined`. Why? Because `val` exists higher up in `firmAnswer`'s prototype chain, as established by the call to `Object.create`, and as illustrated in the diagram you provided.

When you evaluate `this.val`, here's the sequence of events behind the scenes:

1. Is there a `val` property attached directly to `this`? No. Look at the prototype of `this` (which is the object `answer`).
2. Is there a `val` property attached directly to `answer`? Yes. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firmAnswer = Object.create(answer);
```

The above statement means that 'firmAnswer' inherits all 'answer' propeties & methods, the answer.get() method is overriden by firmAnswer.get() but the val property is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it runs:

1. you call `firmAnswer.get()`;
2. the vm calls `fn2`, with `this` set to `firmAnswer`;
3. the vm fetches `this.val`, with `this` set to `firmAnswer`;
4. does `firmAnswer` define a property `val`? No, so let's look in the *prototype* of `firmAnswer`;
5. the prototype of `firmAnswer` has been specified with `Object.create(answer)`, so it is `answer`;
6. does `answer` define a property `val`? Yes, and it's `42`;
7. so, in step `3`, `this.val` is `42`;
8. step `2` returns `42!!`.

Answer (score 1):

'this' is firmAnswer, but it is still inheriting from answer since using Object.create sets up the inheritance with answer.  So it looks for .val on itself, does not find it, and then goes to answer and picks it up from there.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create for info about Object.create.